# Check boxes will not show on web page but no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im not getting any errors but the checkbox will not show on the page? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFSwj.png)

I want to style my checkboxes but i can't if it doesn't show. If anybody can look at my code and see why it's not showing it will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-12 col-xl-11">
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_hungry %> Hungry
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :uplifted %> Uplifted
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_euphoric %> Euphoric
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_energetic %> Energetic
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_creative %> Creative
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_focused %> Focused
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_relaxed %> Relaxed
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_happy %> Happy
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_balanced %> Balanced
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_painrelief %> Pain Relief
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <%= f.check_box :is_sleepy %> Sleepy
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Technically, nothing wrong with the checkbox control. Do you use any CSS library for the UI?

Comment: Where is your form tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using the `f.check_box` but you don't have the form tag. If you don't want it you should use the check box like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'Hungry', 'yes', id: 'is_hungry' %> Hungry
```

Documentation:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag